# Slowly increasing memory usage of Dask Sheduler

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm running a test:

```
client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')

def x(i):
    return {}

while True:
    start = time.time()
    a = client.submit(randint(0,1000000))
    res = a.result()
    del a
    end = time.time()
    print("Ran on %s with res %s" % (end-start, res))

client.shutdown()
del client
```

I used it (with more code) to get an estimate of my queries performance. But for this example I've removed all things I could think of.

The above code leaks roughly 0.1 MB per second, which I would guesstimate to roughly 0.3MB per 1000 calls.

Am I doing something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

My python debugging skills are a bit rusty (and with a bit I mean I last used objgraph on Orbited (the precursor to websockets) in 2009 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/orbited) but from what I can see, checking to number of references before and after:

Counting objects in the scheduler, before and after using `objgraph.show_most_common_types()`

```
| What        | Before           | After  |  Diff   |  
|-------------+------------------+--------|---------+
| function    | 33318            | 33399  |   81    | 
| dict        | 17988            | 18277  |   289   |  
| tuple       | 16439            | 28062  | 11623   | 
| list        | 10926            | 11257  |  331    | 
| OrderedDict | N/A              | 7168   | 7168|
```

It's not a huge number of RAM in any case, but digging deeper I found that t scheduler._transition_counter is 11453 and scheduler.transition_log is filled with:

```
 ('x-25ca747a80f8057c081bf1bca6ddd481', 'released', 'waiting', 
      OrderedDict([('x-25ca747a80f8057c081bf1bca6ddd481', 'processing')]), 4121), 
 ('x-25ca747a80f8057c081bf1bca6ddd481', 'waiting', 'processing', {}, 4122), 
 ('x-25cb592650bd793a4123f2df39a54e29', 'memory', 'released', OrderedDict(), 4123), 
('x-25cb592650bd793a4123f2df39a54e29', 'released', 'forgotten', {}, 4124), 
 ('x-25ca747a80f8057c081bf1bca6ddd481', 'processing', 'memory', OrderedDict(), 4125), 
 ('x-b6621de1a823857d2f206fbe8afbeb46', 'released', 'waiting', OrderedDict([('x-b6621de1a823857d2f206fbe8afbeb46', 'processing')]), 4126)
```

**First error on my part**
Which of course led me to realise the first error on my part was not configuring transition-log-length.

After setting configuration `transition-log-length` to 10:

```
| What           | Before   | After  |  Diff   | 
| ---------------+----------+--------+---------|
| function       | 33323    | 33336  |  13     |
| dict           | 17987    | 18120  |  133    | 
| tuple          | 16530    | 16342  |  -188   |
| list           | 10928    | 11136  |  208    |
| _lru_list_elem | N/A      | 5609   |  5609   |
```

A quick google found that `_lru_list_elem`  is made by `@functools.lru_cache` which in turn is in invoked in [key_split](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/master/distributed/utils.py#L359) (in `distributed/utils.py`)

Which is the LRU cache, of up to 100 000 items.

**Second try**
Based on the code it appears as Dask should climb up to roughly 10k `_lru_list_elem`

After running my script again and watching the memory it climbs quite fast up until I approach 100k _lru_list_elem, afterwards it stops climbing almost entirely.

This appears to be the case, since it pretty much flat-lines after 100k

[image: Memory usage for Dask]

So no leak, but fun to get hands dirty on Dask source code and Python memory profilers

Answer (score 0):

For diagnostic, logging, and performance reasons the Dask scheduler keeps records on many of its interactions with workers and clients in fixed-sized deques.  These records do accumulate, but only to a finite extent.

We also try to ensure that we don't keep around anything that would be too large.

Seeing memory use climb up until a nice round number like what you've seen and then stay steady seems to be consistent with this.